# How to configure Terminator to be opened by default with a custom profile?

Tags: terminator

For `Terminator` is possible create custom profiles, it mostly to define colors.

**Question**

How to configure `Terminator` to be opened by default with a custom profile?

As a *workaround*

Through *Preferences*, in the `Global` tab: having check it the `Re-use Profiles for new Terminals` checkbox. When `Terminator` is opened as **a new window**, *and changed manually the profile*, when is opened a new tab it re-uses the custom profile.

Comment: It fully depends on how that was implemented in Terminator, i.e., you will need to consult the documentation. For `gnome-terminal` you have to work with command line options. A traditional way to make some options `default`  is to define an alias.

Comment: @vanadium `gnome-terminal` lets you pick in its graphical Preferences dialog which profile you wish to make the default. Way more convenient and robust than defining a shell alias which, for example, isn't taken into account when launching the app from the graphical desktop (and how else would you reasonably start a terminal emulator?).

Comment: @egmont OK, then it is better than I taught. Likely Terminator also has such feature. My main point is: it depends fully on how the terminal emulator allows to configure that. Note that there are obviously also ways to launch graphical applications with customized command lines, where an alias indeed will not work.